# How do I style the contents of a JQuery dialog box?

Tags: jquery, dialog, styles, jquery-ui-dialog

**I'm trying to click a link & put that text into a jquery dialog WITH its original styling (not the dialog's style)?**

I'm using jquery to do an element selection by mouse (like Firebug), then once I click on the element I want to add it into a `div` inside a jquery dialog box. Everything works fine except the styling - I want the clicked element's style to be the same INSIDE the dialog box as it is on the third party page.

I've used *www.wsj.com* as the example here, but it could be any site - when it opens click on the SUBSCRIBE or LOGIN links on the right (they are orange until you hover, at which point they go white).

So - if I click on SUBSCRIBE - all I want is to have an ORANGE link in the dialog box of the same font-size and family as it is on *www.wsj.com.*

**Notes:**

- If it's not possible to get the original non-hover color (orange) I'd settle for the hover color (white). I just don't want the color dictated by the dialog box styling (whatever it is - shown in this example as blue).
- I need the 'hello world' div to be styled by the dialog box CSS, as it currently is

I suspect something around `dialogClass` might do it but I can't get that to work.

Thanks to anyone who can help me here!

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid green; background: #1f84f5 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_75_1f84f5_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20pt; }
    .ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; background: #ffffff url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #222222;  font-size: 20pt;}
</style>
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    var horiz = ($j(window).width() / 2) - (750 / 2);
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        // MOUSE ENTER  
        $j("div,a").mouseenter(function (e) {
            $j(this).css("outline","3px solid green");
            var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
            stuff = target.outerHTML;
        });
        // MOUSE OUT    
        $j("div,a").mouseout(function (e) {
            $j(this).css("outline","0px solid");
        });
        // CLICK    
        $j("div,a").click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            var thisCOL = $j(this).css("color"); 
            alert('to check : thisCOL='+thisCOL);
            document.getElementById('contents').innerHTML = stuff;
            $j( "#thedialog" ).dialog({
                title: "Dialog",
                height:'auto', 
                minHeight:300, 
                width:780,
                position: [horiz,50],
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Cancel": function() {$j(this).dialog( "close" ); },
                    "Save": function() {$j('#myform').submit(); }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php 
    $url = 'http://www.wsj.com';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = '<head><base href='.$url.'/></head>'.$data;
    echo $data;
?>
<div id="thedialog" title="Simple dialog box" style="display:none">
    <div id="something">Hello world</div>  <!-- I need this to stay black, not inherit the wsj.com color -->
    <div id="contents">I want this text to be styled</div>  <!-- to be the right color from wsj.com -->
</div>
<!-- FORM submission code from dialog SAVE button left out for clarity  -->
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to maintain the link colors etc inside of the dialogs is to just put another css addition to your current `a {}` css.

**#1:**`a, body .ui-widget-content a { /* whatever you want for both of them */ }` body added to trump css specification-wise the css added by jQuery UI.

[**example #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8H9f/)

**#2:** `#keepOriginal a { color:#5279a4; }` #keepOriginal being some Div around it (or even a div wrapper around all your pages.)

[**example #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/qzduy/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem, though, is until I click on the element in the 3rd party site I don't know the styles, so I can't code them up-front, I need to do it on-the-fly. For example, I've assigned the font color style to variable `thisCOL` on-the-fly, but I'm still unsure how to take that variable and apply it to the style in the dialog?

Comment: Just use jQuery after the dialog is opened, `$('.ui-widget-content a').css('color', _dynamicColorHexHere.toString());` Set the color that way

Comment: So I've added `a, body .ui-widget-content a { color:green; }` into the HEAD and `$('.ui-widget-content a').css('color', hexvar.toString());` into the JS, where hexvar = #ff0000 (red), and all I get is a green link in the dialog box. So I'm missing the passing of the red style into the dialog box (no doubt I've not quite correctly implemented your suggestion!). BTW the selector I'm using will be used for ANY html tag, so I'm also wondering if the use of 'A' anchor only in this CSS is not scalable out to all tags?

Comment: Hmm try within your `dialog({ })` adding another literal object, `open: function () { **put the JS here** }` You want to be running that jQuery css change when it opens. And yeah you probably don't need the `a` part alone in the normal css (I didn't know it was all third party stuff)