# Trouble getting a Jquery dialog box to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I launch a jquery dialog box that has it's 'normal' `color` styled as black. Inside the dialog box there is a `div` (separate to the dialog's main `div` container) that contains text (say "mickeymouse").

I have a javascript variable `var=mycolor` that holds an html `color` (the color often changes, just before the dialog box is launched, so the color needs to stay in a variable).

If var `mycolor=red` I can't work out how to color the "mickeymouse" text in red (or whatever color `mycol` currently holds), while leaving the rest of the dialog box contents in its 'normal' black color.

I originally posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202448/how-do-i-style-the-contents-of-a-jquery-dialog-box) but realised afterwards it was too lengthy. Plus, since then I've played around with the `dialogClass` from jquery and wanted to mention I can't get that to work, so I've posted this as a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for…

But if you want to change the colour of the div with the id “disney” using JQuery you can just do

```
$("#disney").css("color", "yourcolour");
```

You can then replace "youcolour" with the variable you talked about.

---

i've butchered some code together to show you what i mean. It will open a dialog and then change the text in it to the colour specified by "myColour"

JavaScript

```
var myColour = "red"

$(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        change();
        return false;
    });

});

function change(){
    $("#newColour").css("color", myColour);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="dialog">
<div>test</div>
<div id="newColour">Text that changes Colour</div>

</div>


<p><a href="#" id="dialog_link" >Open Dialog</a></p>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - yes you're right (if I was using the "disney" `div` as a standalone div). However, because it's launched within the "thedialog" box by jquery's dialog command, you can't access the css of elements INSIDE the dialog box using css() in the way you suggest - you have to do it with `dialogClass` as part of the 'dialog' call, as I've done in my answer below. I just can't get the variable to be used in the `.dialoghoney` class.

Comment: Hmm, i'm pretty sure that you should be able to. All the dialog command is doing to theming the div then displaying it. You'll still be able to access everything within it the same way you would with any other elements on the page.

Comment: No it doesn't work - just tried it (I read elsewhere it's all to do with how jquery handles the dialog box loading)

Answer (score 0):

So I've broken down the problem into TWO parts:

1. being able to assign a STATIC `color` to a `div` inside a dialog box
2. change the STATIC `color` to a DYNAMIC one held in a variable

The good news is I've solved part 1 - "hurray for me" (I'll cheer for me, since I'm on my own here in SO on this problem with no-one helping me - it's a lonely place!)

For any other lost soul like me - here's the answer to part 1:

a) add an ID to the `div` inside the main dialog box `div` (I've used "disney" here):

```
<div id="thedialog">
    <div>goofy</div>
    <div id="disney">mickeymouse</div>
</div>
```

b) add a new class that refers to the above ID ('dialoghoney' can be any name):

```
.dialoghoney #disney {color:yellow; }
```

c) add a `dialogClass` line INSIDE the dialog code:

```
$( "#thedialog" ).dialog({
    title: "Life's like a box of chocolates....",
    dialogClass:"dialoghoney"
});
```

The result of the above is that "goofy" takes the correct color of the main dialog (black in my case), whereas "mickeymouse" takes the new color of yellow.

Now, that solves the STATIC color of PART 1.

PART 2 I can't do, so if anyone can help that would be wonderful!